# Bitbucket git push

Tags: git, bitbucket, push

I am trying to push my local files to my remote repository on Bitbucket but I keep getting this error.

```
git commit -m "lis8458 initial push"
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 4 commits.
```

(use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

```
Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': myuser
Password for 'https://myuser@bitbucket.org': 
remote: Unauthorized fatal: Authentication failed for 
'https://bitbucket.org/myuser/lis8458/'
```

and I correctly typed in my user and password. I even reset my password and tried 3 more times and it keeps denying my authorization when I try to PUSH local files????

Comment: "initial push" - did you create the repository in Bitbucket already?

Comment: I initialized it and created both repository locally and in bitbucket and ive pushed files to the remote repository before. The problem I am having is terminal is not authenticating my user and pass for bitbucket, thus preventing me from pushing my local files

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: can you post the output of `git remote -v` ?